# recoding a string vector using multiple words

Tags: r, stringr

I have the following two vectors:

```
vector1 <- c("Canada", "EEUU", "EE UU", "Uruguay", "Madrid", "Peru", "Chile")   
vector2 <- c("EEUU", "EE UU", "Madrid")
```

I want to find if the vector1 matches **at least** one word from vector2. The outcome should be:

```
# FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

I know how to do it one by one,

```
vector3 <- "EEUU"
str_detect(vector1, vector3)
# FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

But there must be a way to do it all at the same time. I know it's a simple question, but I haven't find an answer that addresses it directly.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for the `match` function (or its shortcut `%in%`): http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/match.html

```
vector1 %in% vector2
```

Comment: Thanks! (Sorry for the lame edit. I'll keep attention to format next time).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
vector1 %in% vector2
```

also read `?match` and if you're looking to set operations, read `?union` and `?intersect`